# how to keep selected on selected row in datagridview on formload

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datagridview. I want to keep the selected row on form_load. I am using a timer in which the datagridview is refreshing. But there I want the cursor to be on selected row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
dataGridView.Rows[index].Selected = true;
```

Set `index` the index of the row you want to keep selected, then put it on your refresh method.

**UPDATE**

add the `SelectionChanged` event to your `DataGridView` then get the selected row index by `dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;` property like so:

```
int selectedRowIndex;

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectedRowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
}
```

Comment: I am rebinding the grid in timer event. Is it due to that its not working?

Comment: Put this line after your rebinding it. And for testing just set the `index` for example 13.

Comment: Yes, I put 13. It is remaining on 13th row. Now How can I get selectedrow Index?

Comment: Thanks. It is working. One more question. The row is kept selected means highlighted. How Can I keep the cursor also in the same row.

Comment: You're welcome :) hmmm... you need to store mouse cursor coordinates when you click on `DataGridView`, then when you rebinding just set that coordinate to your mouse position. Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) article. But I don't think, that this is necessary option.

Answer (score 0):

To move the cursor in the selected row, you need to point out the current cell.For selecting current cell, you can use selected row index with one of the column index in the selected row.
You can do like this :

```
dgv.CurrentCell = dgv[columnIndex,rowIndex];
```

Or,

```
dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex];
```

Comment: I am rebinding the grid in timer event. Is it due to that its not working?

Comment: After rebinding in timer event, are you calling above code?